# How to do a regex search in a GtkSourceBuffer

Tags: regex, python-3.x, gtk3

I am using `GtkSourceView` with a `GtkSourceBuffer`.

I need to do a regular expression search on its contents, and I know that `GtkSourceBuffer` is a subclass of `GtkTextBuffer`.

I'd like to do something like the Python code below, where `search_text` is a regular expression.

```
search_text = 'some regular expression'
source_buffer = source_view.get_buffer()
match_start = source_buffer.get_start_iter()
result = match_start.forward_search(search_text, 0, None)
if result:
    match_start, match_end = result
    source_buffer.select_range(match_start, match_end)
```

The regex isn't too complex: `search_text = '/file_name\S*'`. (Basically I want to match all file names in a document that are preceded by a separator character `/`, start with a common file name, and end with a sequence of non-space characters, including the file extension).

The [`Gtk.GtkTextIter.forward_search()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextIter.html#gtk-text-iter-forward-search) function only seems to accept these three flags, so I do not see a way of specifying that the search string is a regular expression...

```
Gtk.TextSearchFlags.VISIBLE_ONLY
Gtk.TextSearchFlags.TEXT_ONLY
Gtk.TextSearchFlags.CASE_INSENSITIVE
```

How can I achieve a regex search on GtkSourceBuffer or GtkTextBuffer ?

Comment: *I want to match all file names in a document that are preceded by a separator character ``\``* - then why does your regex start with `/`? There is no mentioning that the method accepts a regex at all.

Comment: Good catch!.. I fixed the typo. This is on Linux, so I should have typed `/` instead of the `\\` separator. You are right: There is no text search flag that allows specifying "regex", so ostensibly the method doesn't accept regex. So how can this be done? (Also, do you think I remove the "regex" tag from this post?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [SearchSettings](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GtkSource-4/classes/SearchSettings.html#GtkSource.SearchSettings), which allows you to [enable regex](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GtkSource-4/classes/SearchSettings.html#GtkSource.SearchSettings.set_regex_enabled) and [set search text](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GtkSource-4/classes/SearchSettings.html#GtkSource.SearchSettings.set_search_text). 
After that you create a [SearchContext](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GtkSource-4/classes/SearchContext.html#GtkSource.SearchContext) and use it to search (`forward` or `backward` methods)

Also GktTextBuffer can return it's text with [get_text](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TextBuffer.html#Gtk.TextBuffer.get_text), but it's not what you are looking for.

Comment: Worked perfectly! +1 for providing the API links and explaining the sequence of steps.